# PHP-Related Post with description by category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordress install. Now I want to add related post with category with some description.
so I created this.

```
<div class="related">
    <h3>Related Articles</h3>
    <?php
        $orig_post = $post;
        global $post;
        $tags = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);

        if ($tags) {
            $tag_ids = array();
        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
            $args=array(
                'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                'posts_per_page'=>4, // Number of related posts to display.
                'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );

        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <div class="relatedthumb">
            <a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,100)); ?><br />
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Now when I paste this code into my wordpress blog it is not working please help.
what is wrong in this code.

Comment: **it is not working** - you mean it stays at home and watch TV? or it's producing any errors?

Comment: <?php

$related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'numberposts' => 5, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
setup_postdata($post); ?>
 <ul> 
        <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>   
<?php }
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

Comment: First of all, don't post code in comments, it is unreadable. File an [edit] and post all relevant code **inside** your question. Secondly, *it is not working* is not a valid problem description. What **exactly** is not happening that should, or what is happening that shouldn't. Answer this in form of an [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Try To Add this code inside your single.php after a loop wherever you want to show related post

```
<?php

    $related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'numberposts' => 4, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
    if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post); ?>
     <ul> 
            <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```